# Get real Height of div (Jquery)

Tags: jquery

I want to know the real height of a div.

if i ask for `$var.height()` he just tell me the fix css height.

How can I get the real height of the div and not the fixed css height.

Comment: What do you mean `real height`? Have you tried `$var.outerHeight()`?

Comment: I give a div for example the css height 500px. Now it gets content. The content may is longer then 500px so i ask for height but it allways tell me 500

Comment: @AskLo what you said ***does not make sense*** at all. If you set a fixed height for any element, it will just be fixed at that set value, cannot be shrunken/expanded according to its content size. If you mean you want to get that dynamic/flexible size of an element, the `.outerHeight()` or `height()` should work (it's based on `getComputedStyle`).

Comment: See this demo https://jsfiddle.net/y1uk74dz/ (the red border does not expand to contain the whole content). Content can be overflown, that's a designed behavior in HTML rendering. So you cannot expect an element with fixedly set dimensions to report the size of its dynamic content unless you tell it to track the content size (which means no fixed size is set here). You always need a wrapper (may not be your element) to track this size info and of course that wrapper's size should not be set fixedly.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried outerHeight(), May be this will help you, try this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    alert("Outer height of div: " + $("div").outerHeight());
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 3px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div></div><br>

<button>Display the outer height of div</button>
<p>outerHeight() - returns the outer height of an element (includes padding and border).</p>
```

Comment: OuterHeight allways gives me the fixed css height + margin/padding but not the real height. I have a fix height in css.

Answer (score 3):

jquery have `outerHeight()` function.

http://api.jquery.com/outerheight/

> Get the current computed outer height (including padding, border, and optionally margin)

Comment: allways gives me the same height